# sql query to get data from two tables when one column name is same in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table

```
custd
name        email               no
kuldeep kldthakur@gmail.com     99
```

and second table

```
pkd
list    weight type  address  name
p1      100    formal  delhi   kuldeep
```

Now I want to search the detail by name from the database and the detail should be come from the both table like :-

```
name   email                no list weight type address
kuldeep kldthakur@gmail.com 99 p1 100 formal delhi
```

Please tell the how I can solve this prob. with which query I'm using sql server.

Comment: I really hope that isn't someone's actual email that you posted in this question, unless it is your own

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need a join. It looks like you have a foreign key on `name`, so this should work:

```
select * from custd c
join pkd p on c.name = p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select pkd.name   
      ,custd.email
      ,custd.no 
      ,pkd.list 
      ,pkd.weight
      ,pkd.type 
      ,pkd.address
from custd join pkd on  pkd.name=custd.name
```

But we aware that if name is not a unique key, you can get lots of incorrect results.

Comment: This won't work, since `name` exists in both tables, and therefore, it's ambiguous as to **which** `name` your `SELECT` is refering to....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks! corrected. Specified which name to choose now.

Comment: the table is 

name    email        phno  sex  list  weight  type  address
kuldeep kldthakur@gmail.com   999  male  p1  100  formal   govindpuram
atul   atul@gmail.com       988       male   p2   100    formal     gzb 


it is the join of two table and query is
select pkd.name   
      ,custd.email
      ,custd.phno 
      ,custd.sex
      ,pkd.list 
      ,pkd.weight
      ,pkd.type 
      ,pkd.address
from custd join pkd on  pkd.name=custd.name
now how to search the column name with adding where clause in this query